# Get all from left table event if there is nothing in join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the table structure for **Clinic has many Categories**:

```
Clinic      Category

id          company_id | clinic_id | type
---         -----------------------------
1     ->    1          | 1         | pre
            2          | 1         | pre

2     ->    1          | 2         | ext
            2          | 2         | ext

3     ->    1          | 3         | pre

4     ->    2          | 4         | ext

5     ->    2          | 5         | pre
```

Here, I want to get all clinics in the output ordered by first **pre** then **ext**. But, sometimes I have check a condition against **company_id** (`eg: 1, in the following try`) and I don't want the clinics to be filtered out.

**My Try**

```
Clinic.joins("LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.clinic_id = clinics.id").
  order("
    CASE c.type
      WHEN 'pre' THEN 0
      WHEN 'ext' THEN 1
      ELSE 2
    END
  ").
  where("c.company_id = 1 OR c.company_id IS NULL")
```

The problem is, as can be seen in the table structure, if I don't have a clinic that matches a category with company id `1`, it gets filtered out, but, still I want that clinic to be part of output with type **other**.

**Expected Output For Company ID = 1**

```
Clinic      Category

id          company_id | clinic_id | type
---         -----------------------------
1     ->    1          | 1         | pre

3     ->    1          | 3         | pre

2     ->    1          | 2         | ext

4     ->    NULL       | NULL      | NULL(or other)

5     ->    NULL       | NULL      | NULL(or other)
```

**Expected Output For Company ID = 2**

```
Clinic      Category

id          company_id | clinic_id | type
---         -----------------------------
1     ->    2          | 1         | pre

5     ->    2          | 5         | pre

2     ->    2          | 2         | ext

4     ->    2          | 4         | ext

3     ->    NULL       | NULL      | NULL (or other)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `left join` itself, filter the `company_id` like below

```
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.clinic_id = clinics.id AND c.company_id = 1
```

Hope this would help you out.